# Large SQL file to CSV file

Tags: python, sql, database, csv, dataset

I downloaded a large dataset (compressed file 17G (`.sql` file)) and I want to convert it to csv or import in jupyter notebook.

I tried this code:

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
# Open the file
f = open('output.csv', 'w')
# Create a connection and get a cursor
connection = sqlite3.connect('steam.sql')
cursor = connection.cursor()
# Execute the query
cursor.execute('select * from steam')
# Get data in batches
while True:
    # Read the data
    df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchmany(1000))
    # We are done if there are no data
    if len(df) == 0:
        break
    # Let's write to the file
    else:
        df.to_csv(f, header=False)

# Clean up
f.close()
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

but I get an error :

> DatabaseError
>   Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in 
>    8 cursor = connection.cursor()
>    9 # Execute the query
>   10 cursor.execute('select * from steam')
>   11 # Get data in batches
>   12 while True:
>
> DatabaseError: file is not a database

The dataset is from  https://steam.internet.byu.edu/#

Please - how can I do this?

I need some of this data in my project

Comment: If the dataset is an .sql file, presumably you'll need to execute that file so it create/fills a database

Comment: @HoneyBadger can you please tell me how execute that file???

Comment: I don't know the file, so I don't know what database it expects.